# What are the regulations for making a fire while camping in Iceland?

Tags: legal, safety, food-and-drink, camping, iceland

What are the regulations for making a controlled and monitored fire made with the intent of cooking/heating while camping in Iceland?

Comment: Answered here (it's illegal) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34860/how-do-i-find-a-campsite-that-allows-campfires-in-iceland/34864 Reddit thread here https://www.reddit.com/r/Iceland/comments/2dh92h/can_i_get_a_definitive_answer_on_campfires_in/

Comment: The real question is what do you intend to burn?  The vikings burned all the wood 1000 years ago.   So you'll need to bring fuel.